# "See more" text section in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to achieve this type of fuctionality in flutter. Just when limit of 2 lines of text exceeds, other contents should appear as see more just like in facebook and such. And when expanded it should shift down other contents right below it.

This is what I am trying to do:

[image]

Comment: @void Yes, thanks. This is what I was looking for. If I have something I'll knock you again. Is that okay? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes sure, everyone here is always happy to help if you are stuck with one thing or the other.

Comment: if you do not get the answer, i can give you the answer.

Comment: @evan Thanks for the help. But I am through with this issue. :)

Comment: what do you mean, are you ok? or you need it

Comment: @evan Yes, problem solved. Thanks!